# How can I build-in an activity in the own soft keyboard?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, soft-keyboard

I have own soft keyboard:

[image]

And
 Main Activity - dictionary:

[image]

Can i embded my Main Activity into soft Keyboard, like this:

[image]

In the event handler "On Start" next code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FdActivity.class);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_EMBED);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

But my Activity run on FullScreen.

Comment: Android does not provide any of this functionality.

Comment: i think, that it is possible